# Finding similar objects in a large data set

Tags: c#, algorithms, database

I have a large collection of (C#) objects and these objects have a large number of properties, mostly strings and numbers. This collection is stored in a database. When a new object is about to be added to the database I need to check if similar objects already exist in a database.

One way of doing this would be to enumerate all objects and compare each property for similarity. For strings this could be done using something like the Levenshtein distance, for numerical properties I could take the value of the new object, create an acceptable range and check for that. The problem with this approach is that it would be very slow.

I would imagine that there are solutions to this problem. Something like a "flexible hash"? Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: @DocBrown If an object is found in the collection which is similar _enough_ the new object will not be added. As for what actually is similar: a selection of properties will be checked (around 20).

Comment: And what means "large collection"? 10 thousands, 10 millions, 10billions?

Comment: The issue here is multidimensionality. Let's take colors as an example. Do you treat a change in hue the same as a change in lightness, or as a change in saturation? Is cyan less similar to blue than light blue is, even though cyan and light blue are the same distance removed from blue on a [color spectrum](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/color-tone-picker-assistant-blend-260nw-1206823129.jpg)? Your data may be multidimensional and any alleged "similarity index" would need to encompass _all_ of your data's specific dimensions. That's a tall order with little info in the question.

Comment: @Flater I understand. To make the question clearer: The objects in the collection are made up of strings and numeric values. Each property by itself can answer the question how similar it is to another property value. Example: I have a string property and I can use the Levenshtein method to calculate its distance to another value. In my current solution I do exactly this. I enumerate all properties and check its similarity to another value. But this is quite slow so I'm looking for a better approach.

Comment: @Mats _"Each property by itself can answer the question how similar it is to another property value."_ But each property cannot answer whether **the object** is similar to another. Take the example of 3D points `(1, 2, 3)` and `(1, 2, 500)`. The evaluation for property X would conclude similarity, and the X coordinates are similar (equal in this case), but that conclusion doesn't reflect on the point itself. Each property can individually confirm dissimilarity, but it cannot confirm similarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this can be a pretty hard problem, especially when you want to implement it using traditional databases. There are special cases which are easy to solve, you have to check by yourself if your requirements will allow to exploit such cases, or if you need a fully general solution. It makes also a pretty huge difference if you want to check string similarity (with lots of different options of defining what "similar" means), or similarity of single numerical values, or similarity in some 2D or 3D space, or if the allowed range for similarity is bounded by a metrics spanning multiple properties.

If possible, try to pick **one** property, then use some "fuzzy indexing" technique to find all objects in the collection which are "similar" in regards to these property, and hope this reduces the number of remaining objects to a number small enough that a brute-force search for the remaining properties will run fast enough. This will work best when you can identify a property with a huge range of different values, ideally equally distributed in their value space.

So how might such a "fuzzy index" look like?

- if the property is just a real number (or a floating point number), use some kind of [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) for indexing. That will allow to use a binary search to identify the "most similar" values, or all values which are "similar" within a certain range
- for 2D or 3D points, the canonical choice would be a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). These are 2D and 3D generalizations of the one dimensional interval tree, well known from computer graphics and visualization.
- Creating an index for approximate string matching is a lot harder, start with the [Wikipedia article about this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching), it contains some references to scientific papers about indexing techniques for this class of problems. Maybe this article about [fuzzy string matching in PostgreSQL](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fuzzy-string-matching-with-postgresql/) can give you an impression about some possible different ways of defining similarity between strings, but as far as I can tell those PostgreSQL tools don't provide any fast indexing techniques.

For "fuzzy indexing" multiple properties at once, the only reference I could find is [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-25957-2_27), which is not free. Disclaimer: I did not read it, so I have no idea if it will really help you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is highly appreciated! Thank you very much! Lots of new opportunities to explore. I will now try the approach with narrowing down the result set by comparing one property after another. Again, thanks for your great input.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a machine learning problem.

Take you existing dataset and look for groups via classification

[image]

This is going to be tricky with your object having many dimensions. But once done you can now look at a new object and classify it based on its data + your model. Rather than having to look at all other objects.

Essentially this is the same as looking for its similarity to other groups of objects in your dataset.

Comment: Interesting. I can think of using machine learning techniques when I don't know exactly what "similarity" means and only have a set of examples for this which can serve as training data.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be great to introduce machine learning to solve this problem. For me this is a whole new road to explore. Thanks for your input!

Comment: i guess it is a bit like using regex, "now you have two problems" but I think this is a good application of machine learning